# How to properly read Watt of a bulb power?

Tags: watts, electricity

I'm confused about reading the terms *Watt*, *Wh*, and *Ws* of bulbs. Here is the quoted text taken from an electrical book that I'm currently reading on :

[image]

Now I'm take out some points from the remarks that confuses me:

1. 60 W-bulb consumes 60 Wh in 1 hour.
2. 100 W-bulb consumes 1 Wh in 1/100 hour.

My questions are :

1. Why does a 100-w bulb consume 1 Wh in 1/100 hour, instead of 100 Wh in 1 hour? (Like that one in the case of 60-W bulb)
2. Is 60-Wh equivalent to 60*3600 Watt in a second?

Comment: 1. `1 Wh in 1/100 hour` and `100 Wh in 1 hour` are the same thing  ............ 2. think about what you are asking ... 60Wh = 216000W in a second .... i don't think so    ....... if you fill 60 buckets with water in 1 hour, then how many buckets will you fill in 1 second?

Comment: Hi your #2 makes  sense. I'm sorry it is my confusion, like saying 1 km = 1000 m. Anyway could you answer that so I can mark it on. Sorry for such retarded question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does a 100-w bulb consume 1 Wh in 1/100 hour, instead of 100 Wh in 1 hour?

You are correct that 100 W for 1 hour is 100 Wh. If you divide by 100 you find that 1 Wh will be consumed in 1/100 h. If your energy meter LED blinks once per watt-hour then it should blink every 36 s if your 100 W lamp is the only load.

> Is 60-Wh equivalent to 60 * 3600 watt in a second?

We don't say "watts in a second" as the watt is *power* which doesn't have a time factor. *Energy* does, however, and energy is power **by** time so we can have Ws (joules / J) or Wh or kWh (common for energy billing).

Your maths is correct but your units are wrong. 60 Wh is equal to 60 * 3600 Ws (watt-seconds).

Note that SI units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelled out. 'A' for ampere, 'V' for volt, 'W' for watt, 'K' for kelvin (as opposed to 'k' for kilo), etc.

Comment: +1 for the info about capitalisation

Comment: You might point out that "equivalent to 60*3600 watt in a second" is not actually meaningful. 60*3600 Ws (216,000 joules) can be dissipated "in" a second, but this says little about the average power, only requiring that the peak power be greater then 216,000 watts. However, 60*3600 watts FOR one second does specify 216,000 J, which is equal (not equivalent) to 1 Wh.

Comment: @What: I've changed "equivelant" to "equal", thanks.